# How to contain air ions inside a chamber without loosing their charge?

Tags: electromagnetism, charge, ideal-gas, gas, ions

I would like to create an experiment where I would hold ionized air molecules. Most likely negative O2-1 ions. I am looking for the most appropriate enclosure so that the ions do lose as little of charge to the surroundings as possible. I couldn't find any suggestions... Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The ions will neutralize with anything they touch so you would need to hold the ions in place in contact with only other negative objects

Comment: Do you think that if I connect a conductive chamber walls to a negative voltage terminal with high voltage it might work? I know that the coulomb's law would effectively prevent them from touching the walls in this case but would negative voltage equate to a negative charge?

Comment: Do you think that I could store negative ions in a chamber that would be effectively a Van der Graff generator?

Comment: You would not want negative voltage in the sense of alternating current, you would want negative charge. In the sense that a battery has a positive and negative terminal.

Comment: Yes a van der graff generator would keep ionized air as long as it's on as it would constantly be discharging itself. A better solution would a capaciter wich stores ions for a long time with very little dissapation, even years of holding energy with low dissapation.